FT.SEARCH always return nothing
I created an IP database using Redis：
 Schema schema = new Schema()
   .AddNumericField(new FieldName("$.ipstart", "ipstart"))
   .AddNumericField(new FieldName("$.ipend", "ipend"));                     

  await ft.CreateAsync("idx:ipv4",
       new FTCreateParams().On(IndexDataType.JSON).Prefix("ipv4:"), schema);

  //add data 
  var json = new
  {
     ipstart = uint.Parse(data[0]),//ip range start
     ipend = uint.Parse(data[1]),//ip range end
     details = new
     {
        countrycode = string.IsNullOrEmpty(data[2]) ? null : data[2],
        state1 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(data[3]) ? null : data[3],
        state2 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(data[4]) ? null : data[4],
        city = string.IsNullOrEmpty(data[5]) ? null : data[5],
        postcode = string.IsNullOrEmpty(data[6]) ? null : data[6],
        latitude = double.Parse(data[7]),
        longitude = double.Parse(data[8]),
      }
  };

  await db.JSON().SetAsync($"ipv4:{count++}", "$", json);

then add this item:
"{\"ipstart\":16777472,\"ipend\":16778239,\"details\":\"countrycode\":\"CN\",\"latitude\":34.7732,\"longitude\":113.722}}"
But when I searched, there were no results:

ft.search idx:ipv4 "@ipstart:[-inf 16777472]"


ft.search idx:ipv4 "@ipstart:[0 16777472]"


ft.search idx:ipv4 "(@ipstart:[0 16777472])"


ft.search idx:ipv4 "(@ipstart:16777472)"


ft.search idx:ipv4 "@ipstart:16777472"


ft.search idx:ipv4 "@ipstart:(16777472)"


return 0

